# Admin_init not working in submenu page

Tags: admin-init

I've a plugin divided into multiple pages and files based on classes.

The base file (linked from plugin main file) contains code for menu and submenu pages and provides wordpress with their respective files in a subfolder.

The problem is, that the `admin_init` hook isn't working in the submenu page (trying to save values from a form submitted in submenu page).

The main page looks like (the `admin_init` hook works fine if used in this file class itself):

```
class MyPlugin {

    public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_menu' ) );
    }

    public function add_menu() {
        add_menu_page(
            'My Plugin',
            'My Plugin',
            'manage_options',
            MY_PLUGIN_DIR.'/inc/admin/class-my-plugin-home.php',
            '',
            'dashicons-yes',
            89
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            MY_PLUGIN_DIR.'/inc/admin/class-my-plugin-home.php',
            'Submenu page',
            'Submenu page',
            'manage_options',
            MY_PLUGIN_DIR.'/inc/admin/class-my-plugin-submenu.php',
            ''
        );
    }
}
```

While the submenuclass-my-plugin-submenu.php file looks like:

```
function checkit(){

    echo "This code is not working or showing (just for example)";
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'checkit' );
```

**Edit:**

Previously not working and now the working version (thanks to Sally CJ) can be found here: 
https://github.com/nabtron/wp-admin-init-test-plugin

Comment: If it doesn't work from that file, then it's probably because `admin_init` has already been fired. So you should probably just hook from the base class, or the main plugin file.

Comment: @SallyCJ i want to divide the code specific to that page in its own class file. How do you achieve it?

Comment: Check my answer and do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Updated answer)*

Looking at the [simplified plugin source](https://github.com/nabtron/wp-admin-init-test-plugin), the following works:

```
// In class-init-test.php
public function __construct(){
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
    ...
}
```

because when that `add_action()` is called, the `admin_init` action is not yet fired. Hence `Init_test::page_init()` gets called.

However, the following doesn't work because `admin_init` has already been fired by the time you call `add_action( 'admin_init', ... )`:

1. In `class-init-test-home.php`:

   ```
   public function __construct() {
       add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'save' ) );
       ...
   }
   ```
2. In `class-init-test-submenu.php`:

   ```
   function save(){
       ...
   }
   add_action( 'admin_init', 'save' );
   ```

And if you want to confirm whether `admin_init` has been fired or not, add this *before* the `add_action()` call:

```
var_dump( did_action( 'admin_init' ) );
```

To overcome the issue, you can create a *static* method/function in your menu/submenu class, and hook the method from the `Init_test` constructor. Example for the `Init_Test_Home` class:

```
// In class-init-test.php
/* This is a simplified example! You'd need to adjust the `Init_Test_Home` class
   e.g. do `public static function save()` instead of `public function save()`,
   and you should actually load the class prior to calling the `add_action()`; or
   perhaps in init-test.php.
*/
public function __construct(){
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( Init_Test_Home, 'save' ) );
    ...
}
```

Or you can try the code/approach I previously suggested. :) But here, it's slightly different and based on *your* existing code; and this one is, again, for the `Init_Test_Home` class, but you can follow the same steps for the submenu class:

1. In `class-init-test.php`:

   ```
   public function add_menu() {
       // Load and instantiate the class - $init_test_home is defined in the class file.
       include INIT_TEST_DIR . '/inc/admin/class-init-test-home.php';

       add_menu_page(
           'Init Test',
           'Init Test',
           'manage_options',
           'init-test-home', // Use a slug other than the class file path.
           array( $init_test_home, 'admin_page' ),
           'dashicons-yes',
           89
       );

       ...
   }
   ```
2. In `class-init-test-home.php`:

   ```
   public function __construct() {
       add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'save' ) );
   }

   public function admin_page() {
       require_once('views/init-test-home.php');
   }
   ```
3. Define `INIT_TEST_DIR` like so:

   ```
   define( 'INIT_TEST_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
   ```

Hopefully this answer is more helpful!

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this and update you. However also tell me how to fix the admin_init being fired before the code?

Comment: Is the `checkit()` actually a method in the `inc/admin/class-my-plugin-submenu.php`? Can you show the full code where it's being defined, including the `add_action()` call? (Post on Pastebin if the code is too long..)

Comment: yes i just added this exact code block in submenu.php file to see if the hook works alone or not, to isolate the issue

Comment: Ok, but could you please show the code?

Comment: please check the simplified code here: https://github.com/nabtron/wp-admin-init-test-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the code. Please try the updated answer and let me know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for explaining it so nicely and giving it so much time, i'm gonna try them now, but before that can you please tell me which one is more optimum way? to reduce unnecessary code from being run uselessly from all submenu pages?

Comment: Honestly, if all you wanted to do, is to be able to call a method from the `admin_init` action, then you can simply go with the static method - just remember that `$this` is not available in static methods. (And it's just one of the limitations in using static methods.) But as for myself, I'd pick the second approach - or better, the one that I've suggested in the original version of the answer - put the `add_menu_page()` / `add_submenu_page()` in its very own class. I'm sorry if this doesn't exactly answer your doubt, but basically, use what works best for you.

Comment: thank you so much for your amazing help! i got it working with the detailed (and previously explained too) way of yours. updated the working code here too https://github.com/nabtron/wp-admin-init-test-plugin may God bless you.

Comment: Amen :) And I'm happy I could help you! ;)